# Why doesn't ismap attribute respect query string?

Tags: php, html

Let's say I have a following HTML:

```
<a href="crocodile.php?name=alex">
    <img src="alex.png" ismap>
</a>
```

I expected the browsers to open something like `crocodile.php?name=alex&41,18`. In reality, the opened URI was `crocodile.php?name=alex?41,18`, which for my knowledge doesn't even make it a valid URI. In PHP for example, I finish with `$_GET['name']` of value `alex?41,18`.

Is there any reasoning behind this behavior? I'd expect the browsers to parse maps respecting existing query string in the `href`, instead of just appending `?x,y` brainlessly.

Tested on Google Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a valid URL. And it's what the spec says should happen. The `?41,18` is a *hyperlink suffix*, not a new parameter. See [HTML 5.3 spec - The A element](http://w3c.github.io/html/textlevel-semantics.html#ref-for-activation-behavior-2), Step 3.2

> If the target of the click event is an img element with an ismap attribute specified, then server-side image map processing must be performed, as follows:
>
> If the click event was a real pointing-device-triggered click event on the img element, then let x be the distance in CSS pixels from the left edge of the image to the location of the click, and let y be the distance in CSS pixels from the top edge of the image to the location of the click. Otherwise, let x and y be zero.
>
> Let hyperlink suffix be a U+003F QUESTION MARK character, the value of x expressed as a base-ten integer using ASCII digits, a U+002C COMMA character (,), and the value of y expressed as a base-ten integer using ASCII digits.

Comment: No. The query string is considered an integral part of the hyperlink's URL, to which the suffix is added, when the hyperlink [is followed](http://w3c.github.io/html/links.html#sec-following-hyperlinks)